# Adding files cookies PHP (host)

Tags: php, file, cookies, web

Hi please can you tell me what a must to write inside setcoookie(...)

[image: PHP code]

to change Host (for example ".youtube.com"):

[image: cookie screen]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see the PHP documentation for set cookie: http://php.net/setcookie

Examples are toward the bottom of the page.

Note: You can only set a cookie for the pages current domain. IE A page at `www.something.com` can set a cookie for `www.something.com` or `.something.com` but not `.youtube.com`. This is to the security of web communications and is endorsed by the browser.